# Django-postgress: multiple primary keys are not allowed

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

when I am useing `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` and running `manage.py syncdb`, following error raised

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple primary keys for table "token_place" are not allowed
LINE 3:     "signatureid" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "s...
```

model:

```
class TokenPlace(models.Model):
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token, db_column='tokenid', primary_key=True)
    signature = models.ForeignKey(Signature, db_column='signatureid', primary_key=True)
    place = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'token_place'
```

my models work correctly with `mysql` but I must deploy it in `postgres`

how to fix this problem?

Comment: The error is pretty clear isn't it? Just remove one of the primary key s and it will work again. Is there a reason that you want multiple primary keys?

Comment: yes. database design need multiple primary keys and i can't change database design.

Comment: Check if you can work with a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) and set `(token, signature)` as [unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

Comment: You haven't explained why you would need mutiple primary keys. Multiple unique columns would be understandable, multiple **primarY** keys would be illogical by definition. Or are you looking for a single primary key over multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your answer I finally get the question, you are looking for composite keys in Django. Unfortunately this is not supported by Django yet. If you need it there are a few options:

1. Try the Django Composite Key project: https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey
2. Use the patches and explanation given on this page to add the support to Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys
3. Use SQLAlchemy (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for querying as it does support this properly.
4. Use a single primary key column in Django and read/write from/to a writable view which communicates with the actual table in the background.